# detect when css keyframe is done - Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I have an animation that last one second and I have an `@Input`I'm taking, but the `@Input` happens so fast that the animation doesn't take place. How can I know when the animation is done in order to trigger the `@Input` after

**CSS**

```
@keyframes bulkSlideOut {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="displayBulkPay" class="bulk-pay-storage-container">
  <div class="header-container">
  .
  .
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@Input()
displayBulkPay: boolean;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a .start and .done event in your animation triggers that you can call a function or set a value with.

```
<div id="whatever" [@displayBulkPay]="canDoAFunctionToo(anything)"
     (@displayBulkPay.start)="onStart($event)"
     (@displayBulkPay.done)="onDone($event)">
```